# Laravel mix .extract method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

Hi I am using laravel mix with my Laravel 5.5

I have my mix file like this:

```
/* Production settings */
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
    mix.disableNotifications();
}
/* Sass Processing */
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/_bootstrap.scss', 'public/css/bootstrap.css');
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/navigation.scss', 'public/css/navigation.css');
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/global.scss', 'public/css/global.css').options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/cards.scss', 'public/css/cards.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/forms.scss', 'public/css/forms.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/search.scss', 'public/css/search.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/profile.scss', 'public/css/profile.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/event.scss', 'public/css/event.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/entity.scss', 'public/css/entity.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/travel.scss', 'public/css/travel.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/sliders.scss', 'public/css/sliders.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/login.scss', 'public/css/login.css');

mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/css/bootstrap-social.css',
    'resources/assets/css/dropzone.css',
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.css',
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.structure.css',
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.theme.css',
    'resources/assets/css/font-awesome.css',
    'resources/assets/css/animate.css',
], 'public/css/style.css');

/* Global JS */
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/pace.js',
    'resources/assets/js/jquery.js',
    'resources/assets/js/page-load.js',
    'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js',
    'resources/assets/js/jquery-ui.js',
    'resources/assets/js/favourites.js',
], 'public/js/global.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/dropzone.js', 'public/js/dropzone.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/image-upload.js', 'public/js/image-upload.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/googlemap.js', 'public/js/googlemap.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/entity.js', 'public/js/entity.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/validation.js', 'public/js/validation.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/search.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/homesearch.js', 'public/js/homesearch.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/instantsearch.js', 'public/js/instantsearch.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/featured.js', 'public/js/featured.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/tram.js', 'public/js/tram.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/counter.js', 'public/js/counter.js');
```

What I wanted to do is use the extract method as mentioned in documentation:

> Vendor Extraction - One potential downside to bundling all application-specific JavaScript with your vendor libraries is that it
>   makes long-term caching more difficult. For example, a single update
>   to your application code will force the browser to re-download all of
>   your vendor libraries even if they haven't changed.
>
> If you intend to make frequent updates to your application's
>   JavaScript, you should consider extracting all of your vendor
>   libraries into their own file. This way, a change to your application
>   code will not affect the caching of your large vendor.js file. Mix's
>   extract method makes this a breeze:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .extract(['vue'])
```

> The extract method accepts an array of all libraries or modules that
>   you wish to extract into a vendor.js file. Using the above snippet as
>   an example, Mix will generate the following files:
>
> - public/js/manifest.js: The Webpack manifest runtime
> - public/js/vendor.js: Your vendor libraries
> - public/js/app.js: Your application code To avoid JavaScript errors, be sure to load these files in the proper order:

```
<script src="/js/manifest.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

So I have created an empty file in: `resources/assets/js/app.js` and in my webpack:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .extract(['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'pace'])
```

Everything is being processed successfully, I attached all the files. app.js seems to have required content however when I get to the page apparently jquery is not being defined.

What could be the cause? I have installed bootstrap, jquery, and pace throught npm.

Answer (score 0):

With vue, jquery plugins have certain conflict

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Comment: I am not using vue

Comment: my mistake i read this line and was facing same isssue -> mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').extract(['vue'])